# Confluent schema registry not found error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I'm using Confluent's Schema Registry to play with it a bit, but I'm having a bit of trouble when writing to Kafka.

I have the following DataFrame I want to write to a Kafka topic using schema registry in databricks

```
+---------------+-----+------+------+-----------------------------+
|name           |id   |gender|salary|headers                      |
+---------------+-----+------+------+-----------------------------+
|James Smith    |36636|M     |3100  |[[id, 36636], [salary, 3100]]|
|Michael Rose   |40288|M     |4300  |[[id, 40288], [salary, 4300]]|
|Robert Williams|42114|M     |1400  |[[id, 42114], [salary, 1400]]|
|Maria Jones    |39192|F     |5500  |[[id, 39192], [salary, 5500]]|
|Jen Mary Brown |     |F     |-1    |[[id, ], [salary, -1]]       |
+---------------+-----+------+------+-----------------------------+
```

after formatting it to be written it looks like this:

```
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|key  |value                                                             |headers                      |
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|36636|{"name":"James Smith","id":"36636","gender":"M","salary":3100}    |[[id, 36636], [salary, 3100]]|
|40288|{"name":"Michael Rose","id":"40288","gender":"M","salary":4300}   |[[id, 40288], [salary, 4300]]|
|42114|{"name":"Robert Williams","id":"42114","gender":"M","salary":1400}|[[id, 42114], [salary, 1400]]|
|39192|{"name":"Maria Jones","id":"39192","gender":"F","salary":5500}    |[[id, 39192], [salary, 5500]]|
|     |{"name":"Jen Mary Brown","id":"","gender":"F","salary":-1}        |[[id, ], [salary, -1]]       |
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

so whenever I try to write it to kafka using `to_avro()` function it says the schema is not found, I made sure the schema is compatible with data using this [validator](https://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/avro.jsp)

so the writing statement looks like this:

```
preparedDf
  .select(
    col("key"),
    to_avro($"value", lit(s"$KAFKA_TOPIC-value"), SCHEMA_REGISTRY_SERVER).as("value"),
    col("headers"))
  .write
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BROKERS)
  .option("topic", KAFKA_TOPIC)
  .option("includeHeaders", true)
  .save()
```

but it fails with the following message:
`org.spark_project.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema not found; error code: 40403`

I've also tried just

```
preparedDf
  .select(
    col("key"),
    to_avro($"value", lit(s"$KAFKA_TOPIC"), SCHEMA_REGISTRY_SERVER).as("value"),
    col("headers"))
```

but fails with `Subject not found; error code: 40401`. At first I thought it was that the data was incompatible with the provided schema in a data type or something but after validating it I ran out of ideas. Have you guys faced this trouble before?

the schema I'm using for this data is:

```
{
        "type": "record",
        "namespace": "com.some.namespace",
        "name": "value",
        "doc": "test Data message value",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "id",
                "type": "string",
                "doc": "Id for the employee"
            },
            {
                "name": "gender",
                "type": {
                    "name": "genderEnum",
                    "type": "enum",
                    "symbols": [
                        "M",
                        "F"
                    ]
                },
                "doc": "Employees gender"
            },
            {
                "name": "salary",
                "type": "int",
                "doc": "Employees salary"
            },
            {
                "name": "name",
                "type": "string",
                "doc": "Employees names"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: You're serializing a record, so it shouldn't say schema not found (adding value suffix is correct... The Databricks avro function is not open source, so you should reach out to their support team

Comment: yeah, but i'm running this in a databricks notebook

Comment: Right. Like I said, we cannot answer how their own function works, or how to fix it. You could try an open source library instead https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS